# macbook pro - disable csrutil without recovery mode

Tags: macos, startup, recovery, single-user

So, my MacBook Pro just died and it appears to be the standard known issue with the graphics card. There seems to be a [possible fix by moving some system files around](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/force-2011-macbook-pro-8-2-with-failed-amd-gpu-to-always-use-intel-integrated-gpu-efi-variable-fix.2037591/).

However, to do this, I have to disable SIP protection.

To disable SIP, i have to boot up in recovery mode.

MacBook won't boot up in recovery mode - grey screen of death

MacBook can boot up in single user mode however.

There are tales that you can boot in single user recovery mode by holding down command-R-S on boot, but that did not work for me.

What can i do?

Comment: Can you bring it to Apple?

Comment: I did and they diagnosed the problem as a bad graphics card. Came home and researched it and wanted to try this test before doing the $500 logic board fix. If I go back, do you think they can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, and that's by design. If an attacker could disable system protection while the OS was booted it'd be pointless. If you find something, please [file a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) because this is an important security component. Single user mode is the same as normal OSX just stopped a bit before a bunch of niceties load, so no dice there. You'll have to get into recovery mode somehow and if you can't even boot to single user recovery you might have a bigger issue than just GPUs.

You could, potentially, boot using an eGPU if I understand the issue. Issue is an eGPU is hard to find and more expensive to buy than just fixing your laptop.